# thinkstats2 book - Stuck at importing the data

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

It must be very simple, but somehow I am missing something... Apologies for the long message but it's driving me crazy.

I'm reading [thinkstat2](https://greenteapress.com/thinkstats2/thinkstats2.pdf), a free pdf about statistics for data science (beginner level).
It comes with exercises so I'm trying to follow the instructions and import the data. I'll describe the steps I'm following and give the pages, it's like a 2 minutes read.

Step 1a: Page 8 - "0.2 Using the code" - Get the code from author's [github](https://github.com/AllenDowney/ThinkStats2). I don't have a github account, so I dl the code as a zip on my hard drive. Then I extracted the content in a new folder.

Step 1b: Page 9 - Author suggests to get anaconda. From my understanding, anaconda contains many different app you can use through the "anaconda navigator". I have anaconda and will use Jupyter notebook for this.

Step 2: Page 9 - Author asks to run "nsfg.py" from his zip to make sure the reader has all the packages installed. Author says I should have a confirmation message. When I run it, there's a flash of command screen without any error or confirmation message. But if it's all about checking that the right package are installed correctly, I can just add "import x" in my code to add the missing package, so not a real issue here (or so I believed). I moved on.

Step 3: Pages 24 to 26 - "1.3 Importing the data" and "1.4 Dataframes" - This is where I'm stuck. After running "nsfg.py" (I mentioned in step 2), the author asks to "import nsfg", which is his own package created from "nsfg.py"? Maybe? So I try to import it and it's not recognized. Which probably comes from that "not a real issue" in step 2... I checked inside "nsfg.py" and it seems to be code to clean and read a .dct and .gz file.

Questions:

1. I don't understand what I'm supposed to do to make "nsfg.py" run properly.
2. I don't understand how my jupyter notebook would understand the "import nsfg" since those lies on my hard drive. The author does not add any line regarding importing anything from a local drive, or from a url to his github (not in the code of nsfg.py as well, except if I missed it).
3. I thought about just copy pasting the code of "nsfg.py" and running it, but I believe it would not work since the .dct and .gz file mentioned are saved locally as well. So I don't get how the code pasted from nsfg.py I run on jupyter notebook would make a link with those local .dct and .gz files. My python is not advanced enough to tinker that manually...

Help :(  (any alternative solution is welcome)

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to solve this, both worked for me:

Firstly, to replicate what the extracts of the book say, all assuming you are using linux or mac:

1. Hit `git clone https://github.com/AllenDowney/ThinkStats2.git` in your terminal in whatever folder you want to wok in
2. Then `cd ThinkStats2/code`.
3. Then `python nsfg.py`
4. Then hit `python` again to give you an interactive shell which is what the author of the book appears to be using - note the >>> before each command which indicates that it isn't in a Jupyter notebook.

To get this to work in a Jupyter notebook:

1. Hit `git clone https://github.com/AllenDowney/ThinkStats2.git` in your terminal in whatever folder you want to wok in
2. In your jupyter notebook interface, create a new notebook in the same directory as the ThinkStats2/code folder.
3. In the notebook hit `import nsfg`.

I think you are probably getting errors because you are not running your notebook from the same directory as the `nsfg.py` file which means that python can't find the script and so can't import it.

Comment: Windows user unfortunately. I'll try those solutions. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. It should work pretty similar just change the filepaths to windows ones, i.e. ThinkSTATS2\Code. You'll need git and python installed though for this to work - if that's fiddly for you I'd try the jupyter notebook version instead.